# In .Net Core how to validate the password before entering in Controller Action?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity

here is my request DTO to register:

```
public class RegistrationRequestDto 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password")]
    public string PasswordConfirmation { get; set; }
}
```

When I see "[DataType(DataType.Password)]", I expect that the framework check if the password respect the rules coming from Identity Framework. For example, in startup I have:

```
        [...]
        services
            .AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
            {
                [...]
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            })
        [...]
```

so I try to use "test" as password I should have an error 400 calling the API to register my new user. But *modelState.isValid* is always equals to true.

How can I check the password?

Comment: It may be that 'datatype' just says something about the data it contains, and it doesn't necessarily mean that the value it contains is a valid password.

Comment: Probably. So how can I verify the password in this case?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to decorate your view model's property with the following:

```
[Remote(action: "ValidatePassword", controller: "MyValidationController", ErrorMessage = "Remote validation is working")]
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Then create an action (named 'ValidatePassword' in this example) in the controller (named 'MyValidationController' in this example) and add your logic there:

```
  [AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> ValidatePassword(string password)
  {    
      bool isvalid = true;
      //
        validationLogic
      //
      if (isvalid)
          return Json(data: true);
      else
          return Json(data: false);
  }
```

ref : [RemoteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0)